# Why does my collectionview content go under my containerView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `collectionviewController` and  a `containerView` that contains a `text field` and `button`  that on click sends a message.
The `containerView` is pinned to bottom of my `view` with a fixed height.
The `collectionViewCell` is going under the `containerView`.
Like this [My simulator screen how my view is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyVvl.png)

I want the view in way that `collectionView`'s bottom always Stays on top the `containerview`. Like this [My simulator screen how my view needs to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDDD0.png)

I also tried setting `collectionView`'s bottom constraint to top constraint of the `containerView`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you tried the bottom constraint to top constraint you should set the priority to 1000 and on the height of the collection view the priority to a smaller number I think this will work

Comment: I dont have height constraint for my collectionView. So, i can't set the priority of the height.

Comment: @A.DURGAPRASAD is your collectionviewController of type UIViewController ?

Comment: @SHISHIR R AMIN No it is of type uiCollectionVIewController.

Comment: You cannot add any custom views to UICollectionViewController Type. Change it to UIViewController and have a collectionView inside the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding the view from interface builder add leading, trailing, bottom constraint, and fixed height constraints. After that add leading, trailing, top constraints between the collectionview and its superview.
Finally add bottom of collectionview = top of your containerView constraint.

If it`s not possible to add the view from storyboard just create an empty placeholder UIView in storyboard with the same constraints as above and later add your container view to the placeholder.

Comment: I build all the UI using code. I did not use any storyboard. Can you help me in this regrad.

Answer (score 1):

Add your containerView after the collectionView and it will overlay.

If that is not working, use `view.bringSubviewToFront(containerView)` and the containerView should be displayed on top

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ. ah, i misread the question. of course it should be the other way around